# Amazon Elastic Container Service task starts with Fargate but does not start with EC2 capacity provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I was previously starting my ECS task on Fargate and it was running fine. Task definition had `Network mode = awsvpc`, cluster was not associated with any capacity provider.

Now I'm trying to use EC2 "Launch type" (network mode is still `awsvpc`, and target group type is `IP`),

1. I created autoscaling group with launch configuration, using `ami-0da25582fb45be38c` (amzn2-ami-ecs-hvm-2.0.20220822-x86_64-ebs) and specific vpcID / security group / subnets
2. I created capacity provider in my ECS cluster, and associated it with autoscaling group that I created in step 1
3. I re-created ECS service and specified capacity provider that I created in step 2, as "Custom capacity provider strategy", with `weight=100, base=1`, and also specified vpcID / security group / subnets that I used in step 1
4. Now I set `min=0, desired=1, max=1` in autoscaling group. I see that one EC2 instance successfully spins up and runs. I can SSH into it using PEM certificate and when I run `docker ps -a`, I can see that `amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest` container continuously starts, immediately exits, starts again after 15 seconds, exits, and so on. Not sure if this is expected
5. And finally now I set `min=0, desired=1, max=1` in my ECS service. I can see one task in the task list, but its state is stuck in `PROVISIONING` and doesn't change. Correspondingly, no EC2 instance is allocated to it

Seems that ecs-agent is constantly restarting and that's why ECS service cannot use the EC2 instance for the task. Anyone has a clue why ecs-agent restarts?

UPD. Checked the docker logs for ecs-agent:

```
$ docker logs -f ecs-agent
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Successfully got ECS instance credentials from provider: EC2RoleProvider" module=instancecreds_linux.go
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Starting Amazon ECS Agent" commit="a1a5ecbc" version="1.62.2"
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Loading configuration"
level=warn time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Unable to fetch user data: EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request\n\tstatus code: 404, request id: \ncaused by: <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"\n\t\t \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\">\n <head>\n  <title>404 - Not Found</title>\n </head>\n <body>\n  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>\n </body>\n</html>\n" module=config.go
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Successfully got ECS instance credentials from provider: EC2RoleProvider" module=instancecreds_linux.go
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Successfully got ECS instance credentials from provider: EC2RoleProvider" module=instancecreds_linux.go
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Image excluded from cleanup" image="amazon/amazon-ecs-pause:0.1.0"
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Image excluded from cleanup" image="amazon/amazon-ecs-pause:0.1.0"
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Image excluded from cleanup" image="amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest"
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Event stream ContainerChange start listening..." module=eventstream.go
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Loading state!" module=state_manager.go
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="eni watcher has been initialized" module=watcher_linux.go
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Registering Instance with ECS"
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Remaining mem: 956" module=client.go
level=error time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Unable to register as a container instance with ECS: ClientException: The referenced cluster was inactive." module=client.go
level=info time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Remaining mem: 956" module=client.go
level=error time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Unable to register as a container instance with ECS: ClientException: The referenced cluster was inactive." module=client.go
level=error time=2022-09-06T05:20:25Z msg="Error registering container instance" error="ClientException: The referenced cluster was inactive."
```

The role that I'm using for autoscaling group has the following ECS policies:

```
        "ecs:CreateCluster",
        "ecs:ListClusters",
        "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance",
        "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint",
        "ecs:Poll",
        "ecs:RegisterContainerInstance",
        "ecs:StartTelemetrySession",
        "ecs:UpdateContainerInstancesState",
        "ecs:Submit*",
```

Maybe the problem is in AMI and I can use another one? Although `ecs-init` version is `1.62.2` so it's up-to-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the ECS cluster that the agent is trying to attach to doesn't exist. Check the value of `ECS_CLUSTER` inside the file `/etc/ecs/ecs.config`. If it's not set, a value `default` is getting picked up and most probably you don't have a cluster named `default` in your ECS.

**Edit**: You can either set it to the proper value in the AMI and spin up new instances in the cluster with the new AMI or you can update the `user data` in the launch template to set the value when new instances are coming up.

More about the ECS container agent configurations here: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/master/README.md

Comment: thanks, that was it. you probably meant "set it to the proper value in the autoscaling group launch configuration", I added a shell command into its "user data" section to write that variable into `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` on instance startup

Comment: Yes, you can do that also. I'll update the answer.